fyne/go RunNative example
I'm trying to run this example
I'm have an error
"android/386 requires external (cgo) linking, but cgo is not enabled [android,386]"
in terminal after: fyne package -os android -appID com.example.proj1 -icon icon.png
have : "err: exit status 1: stderr: go: updates to go.mod needed; to update it:
go mod tidy"
my main.go :
package main

error "android/386 requires external (cgo) linking, but cgo is not
enabled [android,386]"

func main() {}
jni.h copied from android ndk folder to myexample folder
GCC installed, Linux os, cgoenabled=1
maybe someone has a small example of a working application with any Android Api or tutorial link

Did you try
Go mod init
Go mod tidy

To update go.mod

yes, I used these commands, I realized that for compilation you need to use fyne-cross,but still have some errors :android/386 requires external (cgo) linking, but cgo is not enabled [android,386].

if you change GOOS=android  and GOARCH=arm64 - errors disappear, but new errors appear during compilation "go build -ldflags -w -trimpath -buildmode=c-shared -o /tmp/fyne-work-4002102203/lib/armeabi-v7a/libproj1.so proj1 failed: exit status 1"


I realized that for compilation you need to use fyne-cross

No, you don't need that - you need the "fyne" command to package an android app. After you run "go mod tidy" the output should have changed. Please paste the console output from the compile command down to the end of the output.
Possibly you should check out https://docs.fyne.io/started/mobile
